# PowerShell Log File Processing

Tags: powershell, awk

The goal is to take this awk file:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN  { LastSource = ""                    # BEGIN Block                                 
     ORS = ""                           # ORS set to default a.k.a newline                                
     Sources = 0                        # Variable created and set to 0                                  
     Ports = 0                          # Variable created and set to 0                                  
     FS = ":"                           # Field Seperator set to a colon                                  
   }                                    # End of the BEGIN Block

   {                                    # Open Block               
     if ($1 != LastSource){             # First Field not = Last Source execute following                
        ORS = "\n"
        print " "                       # formatting                
        ORS = " "                       # ORS set to space for same line print                
        print $1, $2                    # printing Source IP and Destination Port                
        LastSource = $1                 # set LastSource to SourceIP              
        Sources += 1                    # Increment Source by 1                
        Ports += 1                      # Increment Ports by 1                
     } else {                                           
        ORS = " "                                                                              
        print $2                        # Print DestPort to current line (multi port per IP)                
        Ports += 1                      # Increment Ports by 1                
       }                                                
   }

END    { ORS = "\n"                         # END Block execute after last line is read               
     print "\n\n" "Total Sources = ", Sources   # Print two new lines and text followed by the variable Sources
     print "Unique Ports Scanned = ", Ports     # Print text followed by the variable Ports            
   }                                                    






# Command Line:
# grep 'INext-DROP-DEFLT' sample.log.txt | sed -e 's/.*SRC=//' -e 's/ .*DPT=/:/' -e 's/ .*//' | sort | uniq | awk -f  Lab3Submission.awk
```

Output = [image]
.

And convert it to an equivalent output through Powershell.

I currently have the following command

```
gc sample.log | sls "INext-DROP-DEFLT" | ForEach-Object { $_.line -match "SRC=(.*?)\s" > $null;$matches[1] + ":" + $matches[2] } | sort | Get-Unique | ForEach-Object -Begin { $LastSource = " "; $sources = 0; $ports = 0; } -process { $ip = $_.split(":")[0]; $port = $_.split(":")[1]; if($1 -ne $LastSource){print $1, $2 $LastSource = $1 $sources += 1 $Ports += 1 } else { print $2 $Ports += 1 } } END { print "\n\n" "Total Sources = ", $sources p
rint "Unique Ports Scanned = ", $Ports }
```

And receive this error [image]

Unsure how to proceed.

Log File for Reference:
[LogFileTinyUplaod](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=87760928039792339224)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Unsure how to proceed.***

- First, apply some [Powershell Best Practices](http://powershell-guru.com/category/best-practices/) (code format, indentation, …).
- Then, after replacing `END` with `-end`, you get a lot of other errors…

The following code snippet should do the job (although it's recommended to [**avoid `Write-Host`**](http://powershell-guru.com/powershell-best-practice-3-avoid-write-host/) *unless your goal is to write to the host only*; instead, I'd build some [PSCustomObject](https://kevinmarquette.github.io/2016-10-28-powershell-everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-pscustomobject/) to store results for further use).

```
Get-Content D:\Downloads\SO\sample.log |
  Select-String -Pattern "INext-DROP-DEFLT\s.*SRC=(.*?)\s.*DPT=(.*?)\s" -AllMatches | 
    ForEach-Object {$_.Matches} |
      ForEach-Object {$_.Groups[1].Value + ':' + $_.Groups[2].Value} | # PSCustomObject place
        Sort-Object |
          Get-Unique |
            ForEach-Object -Begin {
              $LastSource = [string]::Empty; 
              $sources = 0;
              $ports = 0;
            } -process { 
              $ip, $port = $_.split(":"); 
              if ($ip -ne $LastSource) { 
                  Write-Host "`n$ip $port" -NoNewline; # print Source IP and Destination Port
                  $LastSource = $ip;
                  $sources += 1;
                  $Ports += 1;
              } else { 
                  Write-Host " $port" -NoNewline; # Print DestPort to current line (multi port per IP)
                  $Ports += 1;
              } 
            } -end { 
                Write-Host "`nTotal Sources = $sources";
                Write-Host "Unique Ports Scanned = $Ports";
            }
```

Comment: This was just what I was looking for.  I'm going to have to edit it a bit more as it doesn't print out the correct final counts, but this makes so much more sense to me.